# How to pass current_user to Sidekiq's Worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I am trying to pass `current_user` or `User.find(1)` to a worker module but getting error in the sidekiq's dashboard (localhost:3000/sidekiq/retries):

> NoMethodError: undefined method `supports' for "#":String

note: my relations are ok ie:

```
u = User.find(1)
u.supports
#=> []
```

**supports_controller.rb:**

```
def create
 @user = current_user
 ProjectsWorker.perform_async(@user)

 ...

end
```

**app/workers/projects_worker.rb:**

```
class ProjectsWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(user)
    u = user
    @support = u.supports.build(support_params)
  end
end
```

Re-starting my sidekiq server makes no difference. This is on my development machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [`Sidekiq documentation`](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-jobs-input-small-and-simple):

> The arguments you pass to perform_async must be composed of simple
>   JSON datatypes: string, integer, float, boolean, null, array and hash.
>   The Sidekiq client API uses JSON.dump to send the data to Redis. The
>   Sidekiq server pulls that JSON data from Redis and uses JSON.load to
>   convert the data back into Ruby types to pass to your perform method.
>   **Don't pass symbols or complex Ruby objects (like Date or Time!) as
>   those will not survive the dump/load round trip correctly.**

Pass an id instead of object:

```
def create
  ProjectsWorker.perform_async(current_user.id)
end
```

worker:

```
class ProjectsWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(user_id)
    u = User.find(user_id)
    @support = u.supports.build(support_params)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! `support_params` is a method. Could I say `s = support_params` and pass it in along with the user_id?

Comment: Read the documentation, *must be composed of simple JSON datatypes: string, integer, float, boolean, null, array and **hash**.*, if `support_params` is a hash, you can.