# Saving data to database after Sidekiq's schedule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I may have miss-understood the concept of [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq). My understanding is that you can create a background job, let it *wait x minutes before saving to the database*. Am I correct so far (saving to database)?

I have gotten sidekiq [to show my jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34380209/how-to-pass-current-user-to-sidekiqs-worker/34380283) but after x minutes, I don't know what happens after.

**Before Sidekiq**, this is how I save to the database after a post is submitted:

**support_controller.rb:**

```
def create
 @user = current_user
 @support = @user.supports.build(support_params)

 if @support.save
  flash[:success] = 'Yes'
 else
  flash[:alert] = 'No'
 end
 ...

private
 def support_params
  params.require(:support).permit(:foo)
 end
end
```

**With Sidekiq:** [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34380209/how-to-pass-current-user-to-sidekiqs-worker/34380283#34380283)

**The reason to use Sidekiq is that I need a post be deleted after x days.**

Answer (score 0):

If the only reason you use Sidekiq is to delete a post atfer `x` days, you can achieve this even without using Sidekiq:

1. Store the time when the post should be deleted in your database.
2. Create a rake task that deletes all posts where the deletion date is expired.
3. Run this rake task every `x` days/hours/minutes from an cron job.

To create the cron job on deployment / inside ruby you can use a gem like [whenever](https://rubygems.org/gems/whenever). So your rake task would be something like:

```
namespace :posts do
  desc 'Clean up posts'
  task clean: :environment do
    # with callbacks (method 1)
    Post.where('delete_at >= ?', DateTime.now).each do |post|
      post.destroy
    end

    # without callbacks (method 2)
    Post.delete_all('delete_at >= ?', DateTime.now)
  do
end
```

And than just create a cron job with whenever:

```
# just run the rake task every x days at x:xx
every 1.day, at: '1:00 am' do
    rake "posts:clean"
end
```